# Implementing notifications models in Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am implementing a notification system for my application. I have many type of notifications, each of them has different number of references to other users. For example, **Progress Updated** notification has no references to any other user, while **Agency Added Patient** notification has 2 references, 1 to an admin and other one to a patient.

I've implemented all these types as a different ActiveRecord object, and created a model for each one. Each of them acts_as a Notification, where Notification is actable ([see active_record-acts_as gem](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as). Each different type of notification has its own table, and its own very specific columns. Since they are about different events, they have their own texts.

Initially, I hard coded this texts into the model methods, like this:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    actable
end

class NotificationTypeA < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :notification

    def notify
        "This is notification A."
    end
end

class NotificationTypeB < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :notification

    def notify
        user = User.find(self.notification_user_id)
        "This is notification B about the user #{user.name}"
    end
end
```

And render the notifications like this:

```
// _header.html.erb
<% current_user.notifications.where(:is_read => false).order('created_at DESC').each do |n| %>
     <li style="padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 6px;">
         <%= render :partial => "notifications/notification", :locals => {:n => n} %>
     </li>
     <% end %>

// notifications/_notification.html.erb
<%= n.specific.notify %>
```

However, I know it is not a good practice to incorporate view elements to models. Additionally, I can not use Rails Internalization (I18n) methods in models, so I can not translate them.  If I go the other way, I can create a new view for each notification type, which they will only differ in their notification texts.

Which one is a better practice for a notification system? Or do you have any suggestions that make this better? I thought this one is a pretty good until I noticed that it is a bad practice and I am unable to use internalization methods in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not "internalization", it's "internationalization". Quite a mouthful, that's why it's always called "I18n".

Second, there's an easy solution: return i18n keys (along with dynamic data) from notification objects

```
def notify
  [
    'notifications.type_b.text', # or whatever
    { username: User.find(self.notification_user_id).name },
  ] 
end
```

Then in locale files

```
notifications:
  type_b:
    text: "This is notification B about the user %{username}"
```

Then in the view

```
// notifications/_notification.html.erb
<%= t(*n.specific.notify) %>
```

`t(*n.specific.notify)` is more or less like this:

```
notif_data = n.specific.notify

key = notif_data.first # 'notifications.type_b.text'
data = notif_data.last # { username: 'John' }

I18n.t(key, data)
```

#### Oh and by the way

You **can** use I18n in models

```
def notify
  I18n.t('notifications.type_b.text', username: 'John')
end
```